# Do you need to escape hard coded plain text?

Tags: security, html, translation, escaping

I started playing with the Underscores starter theme and noticed it uses `esc_html_e()` even on plain text:

```
<a class="skip-link" href="#content"><?php esc_html_e( 'Skip to content', '_s' ); ?></a>
```

Is it any security risk not to escape it like so:

```
<a class="skip-link" href="#content">Skip to content</a>
```

... or is it there just for the sake of translation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The security risk here is not about the plain text but about translation. You should note that [`esc_html_e`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_html_e) is not only a function for escaping HTML but also for localization (l10n). I.e. other people can translate this String but you don't know what the translation would be. It is possible that somebody translates the String and adds a link or some malicious HTML. Therefore it is better so escape HTML in this case.

Comment: Well since you can not translate plain html content i do not see a reason to escape hard coded stuff.

Comment: I agree with you @leFlake. I just would have used `_e` to make the string translatable and echo it. So I don't know for sure why _s does this.

Comment: Great answer - calling attention to the fact that other people can introduce translations that may need to be escaped is the part I was missing!